# Using Scoring to find Best Match in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a DATA table like:

```
ID | Col1 | Col2 | Col3
 1    a      b      23
 2    a      c      14
 3    f      g      11
```

Suppose I have a POSSIBLE_MATCHES table like:

```
MatchID  | Col1 | Col2 | Col3
101         a      a      11
102         a      b      11
103         a      b      14
104         a      c      23
105         f      a      1
```

Suppose I have a WEIGHTS table like (if you want for the sake of this discussion and simplicity assume all weights to be 1 - I can improvise my solution later to incorporate the weights):

```
Col | Weight
Col1    1
Col2    1.5
Col3    2
```

So for each possible match we would calculate a **SCORE** on each matching column.

```
    Score = Col1 Weight * (CASE WHEN DATA.COL1 = POSSIBLE_MATCHES.Col1 THEN 1 ELSE 0) + 
            Col2 Weight * (CASE WHEN DATA.COL2 = POSSIBLE_MATCHES.Col2 THEN 1 ELSE 0) +
            Col3 Weight * (CASE WHEN DATA.COL3 = POSSIBLE_MATCHES.Col3 THEN 1 ELSE 0)
```

So for example the **BEST MATCH** for the first row: Col1 = a, Col2 = b, Col3 = 23:

```
MatchID  | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Score
101         a      a      11     1*1 + 1.5*0 + 2*0 = 1
102         a      b      11     1*1 + 1.5*1 + 2*0 = 2.5
103         a      b      14     1*1 + 1.5*1 + 2*0 = 2.5
104         a      c      23     1*1 + 1.5*0 + 2*1 = 3
105         f      a      1      1*0 + 1.5*0 + 2*0 = 0
```

**So in this case the best match for ID:1 is MatchID:104**. If the scores are the same then take the lowest MatchID.

Here's a sql fiddle if you wish to play around with this:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9df45/1

**For each ID in DATA how would I find the BEST match in POSSIBLE MATCHES?**

Comment: Best Match is the MatchID with the highest score

Comment: So the solution is to join the tables properly, evaluate the scores and pick the match with the highest score. Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: Yes. Just need some direction on how to do something like this.

Comment: Besides the bold (really, skip the bold), this newest edit makes this a great question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @d TABLE(ID INT, Col1 CHAR(1), Col2 CHAR(1), Col3 INT)
DECLARE @m TABLE(ID INT, Col1 CHAR(1), Col2 CHAR(1), Col3 INT)


INSERT INTO @d VALUES
(1, 'a', 'b', 23),
(2, 'a', 'c', 14),
(3, 'f', 'g', 11)

INSERT INTO @m VALUES
(101, 'a', 'a', 11),
(102, 'a', 'b', 11),
(103, 'a', 'b', 14),
(104, 'a', 'c', 23),
(105, 'f', 'a', 1)


SELECT DataID, MatchID FROM 
(
    SELECT d.ID AS DataID, 
           m.ID AS MatchID, 
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY d.ID ORDER BY 
                CASE WHEN d.Col1 = m.Col1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END * 1 +
                CASE WHEN d.Col2 = m.Col2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END * 1.5 +
                CASE WHEN d.Col3 = m.Col3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END * 2 DESC) AS rn

    FROM @d d
    CROSS JOIN @m m
) t WHERE rn = 1
```

Output:

```
DataID  MatchID
1       104
2       103
3       102
```

Answer (score 2):

In this solution, we do a full join to get all possibilities and evaluate the score of all of them. Then, we assign them a number from best to lowest with ROW_NUMBER. Finally, we exclude all those that aren't the best one with "WHERE Rank = 1"

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(SELECT data.ID,
        possible_matches.MatchID,
        Score =  (CASE WHEN data.Col1 = possible_matches.Col1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1 +
                (CASE WHEN data.Col2 = possible_matches.Col2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.5 +
                (CASE WHEN data.Col3 = possible_matches.Col3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 2,
        [Rank] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY data.ID ORDER BY (CASE WHEN data.Col1 = possible_matches.Col1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1 +
                                                            (CASE WHEN data.Col2 = possible_matches.Col2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.5 +
                                                            (CASE WHEN data.Col3 = possible_matches.Col3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 2 DESC)
from data, possible_matches) AS AllScore
WHERE AllScore.[Rank] = 1
```

Comment: Just noticed I forgot to put DESC sort. I added it