# Searching incomplete data, scoring on best match

Tags: sql, validation, search

I have a table in a SQL database with the columns FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth, Gender, EmailAddress, PhoneNumber, PostCode.
The records are often incomplete or with default values.
I want to create a query to find records and return a "score" for a record that best matches the input criteria. The inputs may also be incomplete (null).

My first thoughts was to use a complex WHERE query but I think that would get unwieldy.
Next thought was to combine the columns from the records into a long string and search for the inputs in the string but I suspect that could be slow and open to mismatches. The table to be searched will eventually have 300k-500k records.

What methods could I use to achieve the objective?

I'm not looking for code examples, more techniques that could be used.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.  What does "input criteria" refer to?

Comment: I think the answer maybe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29414852/using-scoring-to-find-best-match-in-sql). 
However, I'd still be interested in different techniques.